# Setting margin top in Javascript is making the div jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid which can be resized. There is one div inside that form which I'm setting the `margin-top` for div on basis that outer div will be resized i.e. its position will be changed in terms of height and width. Currently inside div is in hidden form.

`margin-left` is working fine, but when I set `margin-top` with Javascript it's about 200px from top at page load. And if I resize my grid. And it moves to location where `margin-top` is 300px.

When I try to open that inner hidden div, it's opening at starting point (200px) and then suddenly flies to new position changed by js `margin-top`. Where as if distance increases from left if we resize then `margin-top` works fine.

Following is my snippet about how I'm setting `margin-top`

```
var offset = $('#maindiv').offset();

var yPosone = offset.top;
var offsetnew = $('#upperdiv').offset();
var yPostwo = offsetnew.top;

var top=parseInt(yPosone)-parseInt(yPostwo);


$('#innerdiv').css({ 'margin-top':top+"px"});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="upperdiv">
</div>
<div>
    <div id="innerdiv"></div>
    <div id="maindiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show css and html.

Comment: `yPosone` != `yPos1`

Comment: This is one of that rare cases when I downvote for **terrible** language, orthography and formatting.

Comment: I tried to edit his post but I don't think he knows how to accept it.

Comment: @DimaGimburg have added the html content i m sorry i m taking offset of upper div which is getting deducted from main div margin which i have updated now.please check

Comment: @Hacketo-its the same.edited that my mistake